# Error with getting JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm trying to read json from a url, but not sure whether the server supports JSONP or not. I tried appending ?soncallback=? to the end of the url and get the following results.

url with ?jsoncallback=? at the end: 200 OK, 
url without ?jsoncallback=? at the end: Status text: (canceled).

Can someone let me know what that implies?

I used the code below (from the jQuery website) to test the json file:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function() {
  console.log( "success" );
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });

jqxhr.complete(function() {
  console.log( "second complete" );
});
```

And got the following console output:

error 
complete 
second complete

I don't know what's the problem here. Is that because of my code or the server that hosts the JSON file.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: most likely, change fail to `function(x,s) { console.log("error: "+s) }` to see better diagnostics

Comment: According to your output, you are not able to fetch the page ( you get error ). You didn't mention if you get a response and what's the response.

Comment: You're saying with ?jsoncallback=? at the end you get 200 OK, isn't that all you need? Where's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I followed your suggestion and found out that's a parsererror. Apparently, I don't need to read the url from an external source anymore, so I am able to successfully read the json locally now. Thanks again!